# How to change modification date for files in dir to match name order?

Tags: shell, timestamps, dolphin

This is a self answered question for something others also might find useful.

In Dolphin, I sometimes switch between sorting by name and sorting by modification date. However, it can be annoying since Dolphin does not change the order for only the folder I'm in. It changes for everything. So I wonder how I can fix the modification date to match the name order, so that a particular directory is unaffected when switching between name and date in Dolphin.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's extremely easy.

```
for FILE in *; do touch -- "$FILE"; sleep 0.001; done # sort
```

And if you want to do it recursively:

```
for FILE in **/*; do touch -- "$FILE"; sleep 0.001; done # sort
```

The `# sort` is only a comment. The purpose is to make it easy to search backwards for the command.

Comment: `*` is not equivalent to `ls`. `*` has the following semantics: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368325/43400, it sorts based sorting order in the current locale

Comment: Yep, that has nothing to do with `ls`, and would work in a system with no `ls` at all! And at least in zsh you can also set the ordering using the extended glob syntax  :)

Comment: Thanks, removed that

Comment: @Ferrybig, so does [`ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ls.html).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, glob qualifiers in zsh don't require `extendedglob` (unless you also turn off `bareglobqual` after which glob qualifiers can still be expressed with the `(#q...)` extendedglob operator).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach (especially [the one before you added the `sleep 0.001` call](/revisions/749816/3)) only works on systems and file systems where time stamps have subsecond precision, and even then, on some, like on Linux with ext4 file systems, even though timestamps have nanosecond resolution, you'll find that some batches of files will have the same timestamp (see [linux: touch date precision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393056) and [Why is filesystem time always some msecs behind system time in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/759880) for details).

Here after a:

```
for f ({1..20}) touch $f
```

```
$ ls --full-time -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.183520078 +0100 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.183520078 +0100 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.187520223 +0100 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.191520368 +0100 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.191520368 +0100 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.191520368 +0100 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.195520512 +0100 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.195520512 +0100 7
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.199520657 +0100 9
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.199520657 +0100 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.203520802 +0100 13
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.203520802 +0100 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.203520802 +0100 11
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.207520947 +0100 15
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.207520947 +0100 14
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.211521092 +0100 17
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.211521092 +0100 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.215521237 +0100 19
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.215521237 +0100 18
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 2023-06-26 07:41:04.219521381 +0100 20
```

(and even a `sleep 0.001` may not help, `touch` already takes over 1ms to run on my system as you can tell from those timestamps above).

It's better with `touch -d '0.000000001 second ago'` (assuming GNU `touch`):

```
$ strace -qqe /utime touch -d now a
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)             = 0
$ strace -qqe /utime touch -d '0.000000001 second ago' a
utimensat(0, NULL, [{tv_sec=1687765504, tv_nsec=213757695} /* 2023-06-26T08:45:04.213757695+0100 */, {tv_sec=1687765504, tv_nsec=213757695} /* 2023-06-26T08:45:04.213757695+0100 */], 0) = 0
```

Where `touch` requests an explicit timestamp which it computes using a full precision clock time request to the system as opposed to letting the system pick the current cached fs time, so you're almost guaranteed that two subsequent calls will get a different timestamp, but that would still not work wherever timestamps don't support subsecond precision.

If using zsh (and with GNU `touch` or compatible), you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
now=$EPOCHSECONDS
for file ( *(NOn) ) touch -d @$((now--)) -- $file
```

Or with standard `touch`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
now=$EPOCHSECONDS
for file ( *(NOn) ) {
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -s t %Y%m%d%H%M.%S $((now--)) &&
    TZ=UTC0 touch -t $t -- $file
}
```

Where `$EPOCHSECONDS` is the current Unix epoch time and `*(NOn)` is like `*` but with `N`ULLGLOB on and with the files `O`rdered  by `n`ame in reverse (captial O to reverse) so you get the same order as in `ls -r`. Then we make the timestamps one second apart going back in time.

Answer (score -1):

As others have already stated `ls` and `(echo) *` sort differently.

If you want to sort like `ls` (or `ls -[some option]`, i.e `ls -r` sorts you could simply use it instead of `*`.

Also notice that "*" is inherently unsafe, because it expands to a list of all filenames which can (in large directories) bring the resulting command line over the line length limit. The shell (depending on shell, version, ...) will react with an error like "command line too long".

Finally, as an aside: it is a safe habit not to name shell variables all uppercase. System variables (i.e. "PATH", "SHELL", "OPTARG", ...) are usually all uppercase and if you name your own variables the same you run the risk of (un-)setting such a variable. Use mixed- (or lower-) case for your own scripts and you are on the safe side.

```
ls |\
while read fFile ; do
     touch fFile
done
```

Comment: `*` is meant to sort the files in the same  order as `ls` does

Comment: The `argument list too long` error is a limit of the `execve()` system call, not the shell when an external command is executed. In the OP's approach, the only command that is executed is `touch` and it takes only one file like in your approach.

Comment: The syntax to read a line is `IFS= read -r line`, not `read line`. But in any case, file names are not *lines*, they're sequences of bytes other than 0 and the one representing `/`. And that included the line delimiter

Comment: To use `ls`, you'd need GNU ls >= 9.0, zsh or bash and `ls --zero | while IFS= read -rd '' file; do touch -- "$file"; done` (`"$file"`, not `$file` in bash, let alone `file`).